# How can I use "for" loop in spark with pyspark

Tags: python, for-loop, pyspark

I met a problem while using spark with python3 in my project. In a Key-Value pair, like `('1','+1 2,3')`, the part `"2,3"` was the content I wanted to check. So I wrote the following code:
(Assume this key-Value pair was saved in a RDD called p_list)

---

```
def add_label(x):   
    label=x[1].split()[0]  
    value=x[1].split()[1].split(",")  
    for i in value:     
        return (i,label)  
p_list=p_list.map(add_label)
```

---

After doing like that, I could only get the result: `('2','+1')` and it should be `('2','+1')` and `('3','+1')`. It seems like that the "for" loop in map operation just did once. How can I let it do multiple times? Or is there any other way I can use to implement such a function like "for" loop in map operation or reduce operation?

I want to mention that what I really deal with is a large dataset. So I have to use AWS cluster and implement the loop with parallelization. The slave nodes in the cluster seem not to understand the loop. How can I let them know that with Spark RDD function? Or how can have such a loop operation in another pipeline way (which is one of the main design of Spark RDD)?

Comment: I'm tempted to remove the spark tags from this question because nothing about this is really spark-specific other than the `RDD.map` function

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the details of my project. It is really a spark application. The problem above is just an abstract of the main problem I met. There will be a bunch of key-value pairs, like ('1','+1 2,3'), saved in the rdd. I need to compare the label and the following child nodes, and return each (child node, label) for all key-value pairs. The whole operation may be RDD.map().filter().reduceByKey() and others. It should be done on AWS with spark cluster.

Comment: have you tried `rdd.foreach()` ?

Comment: rdd.foreach() applies a function to all elements in RDD. I can also apply a function to every element with rdd.map() or rdd.reduce(). Any difference? Actually I tried to set a for loop in rdd.foreach(), but it still just did once for every element. I need to do an operation multiple times for every element, not just once.

Comment: I ran this on a single computer, and it worked well. But when I ran it in pseudo mode or fully distributed mode(like AWS), the result showed that this operation was only done once. Why didn't the for loop work in distributed computing?

Comment: Thanks guys, you inspired me. I will try to put the return outside and use rdd.flatMap() to produce mutiple results for every element.

Comment: I know I'm late for the party, but you could just replace your return with `yield`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return statement cannot be inside the loop; otherwise, it returns after the first iteration, never to make it to the second iteration.

What you could try is this

```
result = []
for i in value:
    result.append((i,label))
return result
```

and then `result` would be a list of all of the tuples created inside the loop.

Comment: I get your point and will try to use rdd.flatMap() to flatten a list of results for every element in rdd. Thank you.